# xcode 8 delete old objects

Tags: core-data, xcode8

for a few minutes i had an second version of my core data:
[image]

this entry isn't available and i would like to delete it.
but i didn't find a way to do this? how can i delete this old unavailable object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the reason your have the scenario is that you have 'Add a Model Version' in Editor and some how hit cmd+delete on the model in the master folder in Finder. You still have original version 'CoreData.xcdatamodel' in your master folder. Here is the how you can clean up the Project Navigation.

1) In Xcode Project Navigator, Right click *.xcdatamodeld and hit 'Delete'.

[image]

2) Still in Xcode, put mouse over either project name or group name ( first create a new group under your project. e.g 'model'), then right click and select 'Add Files to "ProjectName"...

[image]

3) A Finder window will open. Navigate to your *.xcdatamodeld, select and click 'Add'

[image]

4) Now you should get back *.xcdatamodeld file in Xcode Project Navigator clean without red V2 model.

[image]